# The page isn’t redirecting properly when accessing Dashboard\Index page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I could not replicate this issue in my local and it only occurs in our staging server. Here is the code in Login function in Account controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (User.IsInRole(Role.Customer))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Catalog", "Inventory");
                }
                else if (User.IsInRole(Role.Admin))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Admin");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                return View();
            }
        }
```

This only occurs when opening `Dashboard\Index` and no issue opening other pages. I will attached screenshot of the network when this occurs. It is accessing same page. [image]

Is there a possibility that it is because I've set it to https in local but it is http in staging?

After few changes it become like this. Error: Admin/Error?w=Column 'UserId' does not belong to table Table.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should note your programming language, platform, operating system, and framework. I suggest you to learn how to use Wireshark and learn about TCP/IP in order to analyze your web-transportation and find errors.

Your status code is 302, which means that your path `Dashboard\Index` has been temporarily moved. Make sure you placed all the files and directories in their right places.

Comment: Ive checked and file is in there.